# Spring MVC schemas and corresponding jar files

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and looking for some help trying to figure what Spring schemas correspond to what jar files in my project class path. I need to know that since I am looking to upgrade to the later version of Spring. The following is the schemas I have in my xml files

**in my applicationContext-dataaccess.xml**

```
b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd">
```

**in my applicationContext-resourcebundle.xml**

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

**in my applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
```

**in my app-servlet.xml**

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

The following is the Spring jar files I see in the class path of my project

```
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-xml-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.context.support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.transaction-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-acl-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-ws-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-ws-security-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar"
\WEB-INF\lib\spring-ws-support-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar"
```

What would be the best approach to upgrade to a later version of Spring ?Take the version names out of the schemas and just copy jar files into the class path of my project? What Spring jar files do I need for my project?
Thank you in advance for any information about this!

Comment: Are you using maven for dependency management?

Comment: Strongly recommend to use a dependency management tool such as maven, gradle or ivy etc. To find out more about the internals visit the spring.io website and/or https://github.com/spring-projects.

Answer (score 0):

*Take the version names out of the schemas and just copy jar files into the class path of my project?*

***Yes***. By removing the versions from the files, the schemas will be searched and found in the jar files, since spring is stripping the schema version when building the jars. This way if your dependencies are correct, your configuration XML will  be validated against the proper schemas

***With the build tool.*** For what concerns your first and the third question. Using a proper build-managment tool, and using it properly is your best choice, [the following answer can illustrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795677/how-to-upgrade-all-the-spring-dependency/27795747#27795747) a maven based approach that gives you most flexibility when upgrading.

***Without the build tool.*** On the other hand if you can't use any build tool, there's a dedicated [github page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Building-a-distribution-with-dependencies) explaining how to proceed

> Although it is strongly recommended that Spring Framework users take
>   advantage of the transitive dependency management features of build
>   systems like Gradle, Maven, and Ivy, some teams cannot use these
>   tools. This is usually due to corporate restrictions or working with
>   legacy builds. If you're in this boat, you may want to build a Spring
>   Framework distribution zip that contains all optional and required
>   runtime dependencies.

Comment: I hear about Maven and build management tools. What about without using these tools?

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can follow the link to the github page, to learn how to align dependencies without the build tool